# Formtastic: Localize date select labels

Tags: date, select, localization, internationalization, formtastic

Is there any possibility to localize the labels generated for date select?
When I use  `f.input(:my_date_field)` I'm getting three inputs with three labels and the contents of the labels are "Year", "Month" and "Day". I would like to localize those to get them German with "Jahr", "Monat" and "Tag".

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

these translations are supplied directly by Rails date localization, which you can learn more about in the i18n rails guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by editing locale file (de.yml) and adding the following translations:

```
datetime:
  prompts:
    day: Tag
    month: Monat
    year: Jahr
```